# Visual Studio Code not recognizing Unity3d keywords

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, c#, unity3d

I am teaching myself how to create games using the Unity3d engine and Visual Studio Code, so I am new at this current set up.

I am looking for a free code editor that will work with Unity3d (with intellisense) and currently only have 2 options. **Visual Studio for Mac**, or **Visual Studio Code**.

I have tried many possible solutions for Visual Studio for Mac and **I could not get intellisense to work for many Unity keywords such as `transform` or `Time.deltaTime`**

So I moved on to Visual Studio Code.

VSCodes intellisense feature **seems to work as far as creating classes such as `Update()` and `Start()`, but it still does not recognize `Time.deltaTime` or `transform.Rotate()`.**

I have Unity3d external code editor set to Visual Studio Code via `Preferences -> External Tools -> External Tool Editor`. **AND** I have VSCodes Debug tools set to `Unity Editor`. I have **ALSO** installed many extension packs in VSCode that relate to Unity and its debugging software and code snippets.

Finally, I have downloaded **.NET Command Line Tools (2.2.107)** which seemed to work for a very brief time period (**about 20 minutes**).

As far as I know, this is a software issue and not a code syntactical error at all.

And for anyone that it is not clear to, I am using **macOS** (**Macbook Pro Mid 2012 running macOS version 10.14.4 Mojave**)

Any ideas on how I could fix this issue with Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the issue that I was having and the solution to it.

The Intellisense bug I was having was due to the way C# scripts in Unity were being opened. If I double clicked on a script, Visual Studio Code would open that script and the Assets Folder accordingly. **BUT** it would not activate Intellisense for Unity Engine.

The fix for this issue is to **right click** on the **Assets Folder** inside the **Inspector** in Unity and then choose **Open C# Script.**

Answer (score -1):

A link to the unity walkthrough for those of us who can't extrapolate.
https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/Manual/VisualStudioIntegration.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1164521)